# Why is the 40,000th char of an XML document skipped when loading to an XMLTABLE?

Tags: xml, plsql, oracle11g

When loading an XML document of 50661 characters into an Oracle XMLTABLE, it appears to strip a single space character at position 40000, but continues processing the rest of the XML document, why?

I have included a simple test script to demonstrate this problem on Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

```
create or replace TYPE SPCBH_V_COLUMNS_OBJECT AS OBJECT                    
  (
    COLUMN_ID NUMBER(3),                                               
    COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR2(15),                                          
    DATA_TYPE VARCHAR2(16),                                            
    PRECISION NUMBER(3),                                               
    MAX_LENGTH NUMBER(6),                                              
    SCALE NUMBER(3),                                                   
    IS_NULLABLE NUMBER(1),                                             
    IS_IDENTITY NUMBER(1),                                             
    IDENTITY_NAME VARCHAR2(50),                                        
    SEED_VALUE NUMBER(3),                                              
    INCREMENT_VALUE NUMBER(3),                                         
    LAST_VALUE NUMBER(3),                                              
    DEFAULT_CONSTRAINT_NAME VARCHAR2(51),                              
    DEFAULT_CONSTRAINT_TYPE VARCHAR2(3),                               
    DEFAULT_CONSTRAINT_TYPE_DESC VARCHAR2(61),                         
    DEFAULT_CONSTRAINT_DEFINITION VARCHAR2(4000),                      
    COLUMN_USER_NAME VARCHAR2(100),                                    
    COLUMN_PARENT_NAME VARCHAR2(9),                                    
    COLUMN_PARENT_COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR2(16),                            
    COLUMN_PARENT_SUB_TYPE VARCHAR2(9),                                
    COLUMN_COMMENTS VARCHAR2(2001),                                    
    COLUMN_UPDATED_FLAG VARCHAR2(2),                                   
    COLUMN_AUDITED_FLAG VARCHAR2(2)                                    
  );
```

```
create or replace TYPE SPCBH_V_COLUMNS_TABLE AS TABLE OF SPCBH_V_COLUMNS_OBJECT;
```

Here is the test anonymous block

```
declare
  V_XML_PATH VARCHAR2(200);
  V_PARSED_COLUMNS SPCBH_V_COLUMNS_TABLE;
  DDLXMLSTRING XMLTYPE;
  V_TEMP_XML_PATH VARCHAR2(200);
  v_length int;

BEGIN

  V_XML_PATH := '\\ipcbhcs01\systems\231\PW6\Staging\PW-0231-70\AZLASRL.XML';
  V_TEMP_XML_PATH := REPLACE(SUBSTR(V_XML_PATH,INSTR(V_XML_PATH,'\',1,4),200),'\','/');
  SELECT XMLTYPE(bfilename('PWSTAGING',V_TEMP_XML_PATH),NLS_CHARSET_ID('WE8ISO8859P15')) 
  INTO DDLXMLSTRING FROM dual ;

 WITH
    table_data AS (
      SELECT td.*
      FROM XMLTABLE('/xml/table'
      PASSING (ddlxmlstring)
      COLUMNS
        table_name            VARCHAR2(50)  PATH '@table_name',
        table_user_name       VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'table_user_name',
        table_comments        CLOB          PATH 'table_comments',
        table_file_sub_type   VARCHAR2(10)  PATH 'table_file_sub_type',
        table_product         VARCHAR2(3)   PATH 'table_product',
        table_directory       VARCHAR2(10)  PATH 'table_directory',
        table_number          NUMBER(5)     PATH 'table_number',
        table_prim_maint_view VARCHAR2(30)  PATH 'table_prim_maint_view',
        table_stf_flag        VARCHAR2(2)   PATH 'table_stf_flag',
        table_public          VARCHAR2(2)   PATH 'table_public',
        table_updated_flag    VARCHAR2(2)   PATH 'table_updated_flag',
        table_audited_flag    VARCHAR2(2)   PATH 'table_audited_flag',
        columns               XMLTYPE       PATH 'columns',
        indexes               XMLTYPE       PATH 'indexes'
      ) td),
  column_data AS (
    SELECT cd.*
    FROM   table_data td,
       XMLTABLE('/columns/column'
         PASSING td.columns
    COLUMNS
      column_id                     NUMBER(3)     PATH '@column_id',
      column_name                   VARCHAR2(15)  PATH 'column_name',
      data_type                     VARCHAR2(16)  PATH 'data_type',
      precision                     NUMBER(3)     PATH 'precision',
      max_length                    NUMBER(6)     PATH 'max_length',
      scale                         NUMBER(3)     PATH 'scale',
      is_nullable                   VARCHAR2(1)   PATH 'is_nullable',
      is_identity                   VARCHAR2(1)   PATH 'is_identity',
      identity_name                 VARCHAR2(50)  PATH 'identity_name',
      seed_value                    NUMBER(3)     PATH 'seed_value',
      increment_value               NUMBER(3)     PATH 'increment_value',
      last_value                    NUMBER(3)     PATH 'last_value',
      default_constraint_name       VARCHAR2(51)  PATH 'default_constraint_name',
      default_constraint_type       VARCHAR2(3)   PATH 'default_constraint_type',
      default_constraint_type_desc  VARCHAR2(61)  PATH 'default_constraint_type_desc',
      default_constraint_definition VARCHAR2(4000) PATH 'default_constraint_definition',
      column_user_name              VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'column_user_name',
      column_parent_name            VARCHAR2(9)   PATH 'column_parent_name',
      column_parent_column_name     VARCHAR2(16)  PATH 'column_parent_column_name',
      column_parent_sub_type        VARCHAR2(9)   PATH 'column_parent_sub_type',
      column_comments               VARCHAR2(2001) PATH 'column_comments',
      column_updated_flag           VARCHAR2(2)   PATH 'column_updated_flag',
      column_audited_flag           VARCHAR2(2)   PATH 'column_audited_flag'
    ) cd )
SELECT SPCBH_V_COLUMNS_OBJECT(     
                              COLUMN_ID,                
                              COLUMN_NAME,              
                              DATA_TYPE,                
                              PRECISION,                
                              MAX_LENGTH,               
                              SCALE,                    
                              IS_NULLABLE,              
                              IS_IDENTITY,              
                              IDENTITY_NAME,            
                              SEED_VALUE,               
                              INCREMENT_VALUE,          
                              LAST_VALUE,
                              DEFAULT_CONSTRAINT_NAME,
                              DEFAULT_CONSTRAINT_TYPE,
                              DEFAULT_CONSTRAINT_TYPE_DESC,
                              DEFAULT_CONSTRAINT_DEFINITION,
                              COLUMN_USER_NAME,        
                              COLUMN_PARENT_NAME,       
                              COLUMN_PARENT_COLUMN_NAME,
                              COLUMN_PARENT_SUB_TYPE,   
                              COLUMN_COMMENTS,          
                              COLUMN_UPDATED_FLAG,      
                              COLUMN_AUDITED_FLAG)      
    BULK COLLECT INTO V_PARSED_COLUMNS
    FROM column_data;

    select length(DDLXMLSTRING.getClobVal()) into v_length from dual;
    dbms_output.put_line('length(DDLXMLSTRING):'||v_length);

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(RPAD('COLUMN_ID',10) || RPAD('COLUMN_NAME',18) || RPAD('COLUMN_PARENT_COLUMN_NAME',30) || RPAD('COLUMN_PARENT_SUB_TYPE',30));                        
    FOR MY_CURSOR IN (SELECT 
                        COLUMN_ID,                                       
                        COLUMN_NAME,
                        DATA_TYPE,
                        PRECISION,
                        MAX_LENGTH,
                        SCALE,
                        IS_NULLABLE,
                        IS_IDENTITY,
                        IDENTITY_NAME,
                        SEED_VALUE,
                        INCREMENT_VALUE,
                        LAST_VALUE,
                        DEFAULT_CONSTRAINT_NAME,
                        DEFAULT_CONSTRAINT_TYPE,
                        DEFAULT_CONSTRAINT_TYPE_DESC,
                        DEFAULT_CONSTRAINT_DEFINITION,
                        COLUMN_USER_NAME,
                        COLUMN_PARENT_NAME,
                        COLUMN_PARENT_COLUMN_NAME,
                        COLUMN_PARENT_SUB_TYPE,
                        COLUMN_COMMENTS,
                        COLUMN_UPDATED_FLAG,
                        COLUMN_AUDITED_FLAG
                      FROM TABLE(V_PARSED_COLUMNS) ORDER BY COLUMN_ID) 
      LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(RPAD(MY_CURSOR.COLUMN_ID ,10) || RPAD(MY_CURSOR.COLUMN_NAME,18) || RPAD(NVL(MY_CURSOR.COLUMN_PARENT_COLUMN_NAME,'NULL'),30) || RPAD(NVL(MY_CURSOR.COLUMN_PARENT_SUB_TYPE,'NULL'),30));
      END LOOP;
end;
```

At position 40000 the XML reader appears to skip the space and load the XMLTYPE with a NULL, this happens no where else.  If I change the value to something other than a single space, e.g. two spaces, or 'ABC', it works fine.

XML document and screen shot showing the document at the 40,000th character available at https://drive.google.com/open?id=124zDZYiNJnNzenQScgCbT3RKk7SApYPO

You will need to point to an available DB Directory.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be the 40,000th character but the 39,999th. [MRE] at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=12da8b99784aebdad285d29b7a8a1daf).

Comment: Also, why read the data into a collection only to put it back into a cursor to loop through to print it out? You could loop through the collection and skip the cursor; or else skip the collection and open the `XMLTABLE` query as a cursor.

Comment: Updated [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a9bfb29d1d3337fda3eb76084ae1a086) with tests of different strings. It does not appear to affect Oracle 18c [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a9bfb29d1d3337fda3eb76084ae1a086)

Comment: Thanks for you excellent example of a Minimal Reproducible Example.  
This code was just a portion of a bigger SP that does not just spin through the XMLTABLE with a cursor, that was added for the test to display the invalid results.

Comment: I currently do not have access to a 12c instance and have reached out to some DBA in our organization to have them test this at 12c as well.  Would you agree this is a bug at least at 11g?

Comment: Confirmed it works in 12c as well.

Answer (score 0):

A minimal reproducible example of this is:

```sql
DECLARE
  PROCEDURE testClob(
    p_position NUMBER,
    p_value    VARCHAR2
  )
  IS
    p_clob   CLOB         := '<root><a>';
    p_middle VARCHAR2(7)  := '</a><b>';
    p_close  VARCHAR2(11) := '</b></root>';
    p_deduction NUMBER    := LENGTH( p_clob ) + LENGTH( p_middle );
    p_a     CLOB;
    p_b     VARCHAR2(10);
  BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1 .. FLOOR( ( p_position - p_deduction) / 4000 ) LOOP
      p_clob := p_clob || RPAD( '_', 4000, '_' );
    END LOOP;
    p_clob := p_clob || RPAD( '_', MOD( p_position - p_deduction, 4000 ), '_' );
    p_clob := p_clob || p_middle;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT( LENGTH( p_clob ) || ' characters then "' || p_value || '" gives ' );
    p_clob := p_clob || p_value;
    p_clob := p_clob || p_close;

    SELECT a, b
    INTO   p_a, p_b
    FROM   XMLTABLE(
             '/root'
             PASSING XMLTYPE( p_clob )
             COLUMNS
               a CLOB         PATH 'a',
               b VARCHAR2(10) PATH 'b'
           );

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '"'||p_b||'"' );
  END;
BEGIN
  testClob( 39998, '' );
  testClob( 39998, ' ' );
  testClob( 39998, '  ' );
  testClob( 39998, 'ABC' );
  testClob( 39998, 'A' );
END;
/
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> 39998 characters then "" gives ""
> 39998 characters then " " gives ""
> 39998 characters then "  " gives "  "
> 39998 characters then "ABC" gives "ABC"
> 39998 characters then "A" gives "A"
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a9bfb29d1d3337fda3eb76084ae1a086)*

Testing on [Oracle 18c](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a9bfb29d1d3337fda3eb76084ae1a086) and [the OP testing on Oracle 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403587/why-is-the-40-000th-char-of-an-xml-document-skipped-when-loading-to-an-xmltable?noredirect=1#comment103187804_58403587) does not demonstrate this issue.

It appears to be a bug in Oracle 11g (and maybe earlier, but that is untested); so to solve it you could:

1. Upgrade your database to a later version that does not demonstrate this issue;
2. Contact [My Oracle Support](https://support.oracle.com/keystone/) and see if it is a known bug and if they have a resolution for the issue or what they could do to support you;
3. Parse XML data in a different way; however, on [testing](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fbcd7c43c64b6c9b6c6808c4892ae059) `XMLTABLE`, `XMLQUERY` and `EXTRACTVALUE` all suffer from the same issue so a pure SQL solution does not appear to be available. You could embed a Java function into the database to handle parsing XML but this is going to be less performant and seems like an overreaction to the issue; or
4. Build a custom solution to test the 39,999th character for this issue and militate for it (this is probably not a viable option but is included for completeness).